# Best speed/secure javascript crypt alg. for web?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, performance

Currently i'm in searching for best crypt. algolrithm implemented on javascript to let my users be able to store little (mysql varchar(512)) encrypted data on my server, but access (eg. decode) only from local machine in browser via passcode. That's all of course via SSL.

I've found RC4 and RSA impl. But actually i'm not a PRO in cryptography and know a little bit about that dark side of moon. RSA is good enougth, but... too slow, imho, and not a password-way decode.

So the main question is: that crypt. alg. do you think is best in ratio SPEED/SECURE for the web usage (my case) and of coz. javascript implemented already (links are welcome!:).

Hope this topic will be useful in further.

Comment: If you're already using SSL, why not do all the encryption server-side?

Comment: because in this case server (eg. we) will be able to see the data BEFORE encoding. my case: give user right to choose that info we can know and what dont. PRIVACY in one world :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try http://www.fourmilab.ch/javascrypt/ ?

Comment: yep, i've watched this out. seems to be author not support his project, coz there isn't a lib. only functions for his site. and i dont see algorithm (in sources) he using to en/decrypt data.